# Are there code commenting features like DocBlockr in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Sublime Text 3, Atom.io, and Bracket.io as previous editors.

I am also really enjoying the new Visual Studio Code Editor for Mac.

Are there any code commenting features similar to DocBlockr for Sublime?
This is quite crucial for me as I comment a hell of a lot of code.

Comment: For php developpement, it's a planned feature in the [PHP Intellisense Crane](https://github.com/HvyIndustries/crane#planned-features) plugin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Visual Studio Code Marketplace now has a doc block extension for JavaScript & others may be added soon. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevencl.addDocComments

---

Formerly, it had partial support for this. As mentioned by others, you could get it by typing `/**` and then ENTER but only if you are in a JavaScript file. I don't believe it works in any other language.

A few similar features had been requested:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170910095011/https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/9417975-intellisense-comments-need-improved-typedoc-and-j

https://web.archive.org/web/20170910095011/https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7899765-automatic-formatting-of-and-documentation

https://web.archive.org/web/20170910095011/https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/8248872-true-jsdoc-support-for-ts-and-js

Answer (score 6):

It completes the block if you type `/**[enter]` and then any typing within the block is formatted (e.g. hit enter on a line beginning with a * and another is inserted below with a *).

But one really nice feature of DocBlockr is that it scans the code below and adds @param statements in the block. VS Code does not appear to do this.

Comment: I'm using it with the latest, but it seems to be dependent on file extension. It works when the file is .js or .ts, but if it's .cs, .cpp, .php, it doesn't.

Comment: Shift+Alt+A will generally add a /**/ with the cursor placed between the asterisks and that seems to work in more file formats. There's also a VS Code Comment Snippets extension that purports to add them to more languages, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 6):

***As of today, and release v1.1 there are not***, however it is a highly voted feature. I would vote for this feature if you would find it useful, @mattferderer has posted the feature-links you should add your votes to. Until then, there are 2 plugins that work very well well used together:

**[Document This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joelday.docthis)** (`ext install docthis`) will generate JsDoc style comments for many JsDoc style annotations. Use command `Ctrl + Alt + D` on or inside of where you want to generate documentation.

This works well with the plugin "Complete JsDoc Tags"

**[Complete JsDoc Tags](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.JSDocTagComplete)** (`ext install JSDocTagComplete`) Provides code completion for most JsDoc style annotations using `Ctrl + space`.

Using these 2 plugins together works really efficiently. DocThis gives the initial generated comment with `Ctrl + Alt + D`, and can then use `ctrl + space` to add specific JsDoc annotations DocThis doesn't see/generate.

I didn't find the plugin "**[Add JsDoc Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevencl.addDocComments)**" @mattferderer mentions to be very useful. It only provides you with a `@param` and `@return` tag and nothing else...

Answer (score 5):

If you type `/**` then ENTER and you get js doc format in visual studio code

Comment: I do not really get anything except `/**` turning everything below it green until I close it.

Comment: As I note above, behavior is dependent on file type. The autoclose and starting lines with * happens in .js and .ts files, but not in a number of others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want parameter comments for a functions or voids, just type ///
as a bonus they will apear also in mouseover highlights

Answer (score 0):

There is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilbrayfield.php-docblocker.

It's not as powerful as in PHPStorm. But it can detect function parameters and adds template lines for it.