# Is there a "dock blocker" comment generator (/** */) in VS Code for PHP?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have been looking for an autocompleting dock blocker extension - or built in - for PHP on VS Code as it exists and works well for JS.

In Sublime Text 3 I was using DockBlockr which was super efficient in pre-filling info.

Like suggested here: [Are there code commenting features like DocBlockr in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953387/are-there-code-commenting-features-like-docblockr-in-visual-studio-code) I tried `crane` but it doesn't do the comment part, and `Auto Comment Blocks` does not fill anything.

Comment: There is an extension simply called PHP DocBlocker. What do you need it to do? Just to be aware recommending software is out of scope in StackOverflow since that might change over time.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrebs for reminding me that this question has been left unanswered! :p I indeed use that extension and find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very old now, but for the sake of completeness and for later readers, I do use the PHP DocBlocker extension that really does the job correctly.

This is the extension:
[image]

And this is a generated comment for the function below:
[image]

Note that you can even tab between the fields while filling up the first time.